# System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)

Tags: autodesk-forge

BOM export Automation throws below exception.

---

**Exception** :

```
System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32\[\] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)

at Inventor.BOMViews.get_Item(Object Index)

at UpdateParams.SampleAutomation.ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDocument doc)

at UpdateParams.SampleAutomation.Run(Document doc)
```

**CODE** :

```
  var rows = new List<object[]>();

            AssemblyComponentDefinition assemblyComponentDef = doc.ComponentDefinition;
            BOM bom = assemblyComponentDef.BOM;
            BOMViews bomViews = bom.BOMViews;

            // enable structured view in case of iAssembly
            if (assemblyComponentDef.IsiAssemblyFactory && bom.StructuredViewEnabled == false)
                bom.StructuredViewEnabled = true;

 <Place where exception throws> BOMView structureView = bomViews["Structured"];

            GetBomRowProperties(structureView.BOMRows, rows);

            extractedBOM.Data = rows.ToArray();

            return extractedBOM;
```

Can some body help me how to fix this issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we done with param updates, then the assembly document should be closed. Then open the same assembly doc to get the BOM details. Until we close and open the assembly document the BOM retrieve will throw the above error.

Comment: Did you try using Update2() or Rebuild2()? Just wondering if they work for you.
(at least you have a solution with the reopen)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that all assembly components are available (maybe use [Pack and Go](https://help.autodesk.com/view/INVNTOR/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-730304AA-13BD-467B-9351-C7C1362876BD) to generate the zip) - you might also need to activate the right **Inventor Project** to help with file resolution:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/pack-and-go-assemblies-design-automation

The main sample is doing the same thing as your code to get the **BOM** data:
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-configurator-inventor/blob/f5c0ea52e8bef438f2088cd885ccd6b512ad4e2d/AppBundles/ExportBOMPlugin/ExportBOMAutomation.cs#L154

So you can also upload your model there for testing:
https://inventor-config-demo.autodesk.io/

If the code succeeds you'll see info on the **BOM** panel of the web app - e.g.:

[image]

**Edit 2023-12-15:**

You'll have to narrow down the issue. Certain APIs can be more sensitive to things than others when used inside **Inventor Server**,
e.g. suppress requires you to open the assembly as invisible, and some others need that you solve file resolution - both covered in this post:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/dealing-suppressed-components

Try to reproduce the problem with accessing the specific **BOMView** right after opening the assembly, without doing any modifications.
You can iterate on the sample code that you use to reproduce the issue very quickly using this:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/quick-tests-using-ilogic

Comment: Thanks For the reply Adam, This plugin seems to be fine, but i am making a product specific feature which does Parameter update & BOM creation on the same plugin.  
 Is that the structure makes the issue on BOM creation.?

Comment: Added more info under "Edit 2023-12-15"

Comment: MY Plugin contains both Params update & BOM creation and not maintaining separate plugins for BOM & Params update for just to avoid separate plugin execution. Is this approach makes the issue?

Comment: Having a single plug-in is fine, that should not be the problem

Comment: Yes Adam, we can use in same plugin.